# Consulta de Saldo MercadoPago

Tags: api, mercadopago

Alguien sabe si esta desarrollada alguna API para mostar el saldo de MercadoPago
No figura informacion en https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/community/
Gracias!

Comment: Hola Martín. Las preguntas en [es.so] deben cumplir con ciertos requisitos que nos permitan asegurar la calidad de los contenidos en beneficio de todos. Te invito a que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía _"[ask]"_ y se ser posible agregues un __[mcve]__. Si quieres saber como funciona esta comunidad de programadores, puedes visitar el _[tour]_.

Comment: La respuesta está en la documentación de MercadoPago, no estaría bien eliminar esta pregunta?

Comment: Este curso te será de utilidad: https://www.acamica.com/cursos/105/la-api-mercadolibre-conceptos-finales Saludos :D

Answer (score 2):

En la **pagina de developers** se encuentra la siguiente información para poder realizar una consulta de tu saldo en la cuenta de **Mercado Pago**: [Ver Documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/).

> ## ¿Cómo funciona?
>
> Puedes solicitar información, por ejemplo sobre un pago o el saldo de
> tu cuenta, usando HTTP (de manera similiar a un navegador).
>
> **Por ejemplo: "Quiero conocer el saldo de mi cuenta."**
>
> Para eso, debes ir a:
>
> `https://api.mercadopago.com/users/TU_ID_DE_USUARIO/mercadopago_account/balance?access_token=TU_TOKEN_DE_ACCESO`
>
> Y recibirás una respuesta como esta:
>
> ```
> {
>     "user_id": TU_ID_DE_USUARIO,
>     "total_amount": 1000,
>     "available_balance": 1000,
>     .
>     .
>     . }
> ```

Comment: Milton me atreví a editar tu respuesta, añadiendo el link a la documentación que vos habías colocado con una imagen, a su vez cité lo que dice la documentación, como respuesta a lo solicitado por el OP. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Es muy sencillo: Primero necesitas tu client_id y client_secret, lo obtenés de acá:

https://www.mercadopago.com/mla/herramientas/aplicaciones

Luego pedis los datos del balance y filtras lo que queres:

```
<?php

require_once ('../mercadopago/mercadopago.php');

$mp = new MP ("Client_ID", "Client_Secrt");

$balance = $mp->get ("/users/TU_ID_USUARIO/mercadopago_account/balance");

$balence = json_encode($balance);

echo "Total ML: ".$balance['response']['total_amount'];
echo "<br>Disponible: ".$balance['response']['available_balance'];
echo "<br>Pendiente: ".$balance['response']['unavailable_balance'];

?>
```